# chembl_webresource_client install failed on google colab

Tags: python, linux

need your help, I tried to install the chembl_webresource_client on colab, it usually works fine, but today to my surprise there is a mistake in the very first step.

! pip install chembl_webresource_client # install the client

```
from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client # here is where is wrong
molecule = new_client.molecule
res = molecule.search('viagra')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-19aed0e54aea> in <module>()
----> 1 from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client
      2 molecule = new_client.molecule
      3 res = molecule.search('viagra')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/chembl_webresource_client/cache.py in <module>()
      1 __author__ = 'mnowotka'
      2 
----> 3 from requests_cache.backends.base import BaseCache, hashlib, _to_bytes
      4 
      5 def create_key(self, request):

ImportError: cannot import name 'hashlib' from 'requests_cache.backends.base' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_cache/backends/base.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with requests-cache.  I downgraded to 0.5.2 and the error goes away.

Comment: Thanks but I actually not familiar with too much coding things, could you give a bit more specific what I need to do, like give me  a example, like a command line ?

Comment: May be I should mention that if I run the same ipynb book from its github source in colab, everything is fine, but when I loaded it from my local laptop this issue happens..

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed on version 0.10.3 of the chembl_webresource_client. Upgrading should fix it